# Disjoint cycles

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

Suppose I am given an element $f$ in $S_7$, so that $f=(4,1,5)(3,2)(1,5,3)$.

I want to write this as a product of disjoint cycles.

How would I do this?

Comment: Where do $1,2,3,4,5$ each go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the product in cycles (when you're done with one cycle beginning with the next smaller number not in the cycle already written down):

$$f=(1\;4)(2\;3\;5)$$